# How can I fire js-created touch events on the DOM

Tags: javascript, dom, dom-events

As part of a test suit I am working on, I am trying to mimic user behavior. On desktop, I do this by using `document.createEvent` to mimic mouse events. However, I am unable to make the browser fully mimic touch events.

I tried the following:

```
var ev = document.createEvent('MouseEvents');
var el = document.createElement('div');

ev.initMouseEvent('touchstart');

el.addEventListener('touchstart', function(e){console.log(e, e.touches);},false);

el.dispatchEvent(ev);
```

But browser never generates the `touches` collection. I thought maybe `MouseEvents` is the wrong event type but it's the only one I found that made sense (tried `TouchEvents` but obviously got a DOM exception).

I know I can probably mimic this behavior but I wanted to know if there is a real way for creating costume touch events

Answer (score 0):

var ev = document.createEvent('TouchEvent');
ev.initTouchEvent('touchstart');